# Removing widgets from ViewHolder in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to make an app for tracking my spendings.
I have a database with a table called categories. In this table, I save the category_id(int), category_name(varchar), limit_week(int), limit_month(int). If I don't want to have limits, they can be null. Adding categories works perfectly.

Now I want to display the Categories in a RecyclerView. The Layout for the items looks like that:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_color"
app:contentPadding="@dimen/card_content_padding"
app:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLimWeek"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/weekly_limit"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLimMonth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/monthly_limit"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvLimWeek" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLimWeekEnter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvLimMonth"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvLimWeek"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_16sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLimMonthEnter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvLimMonth"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvLimMonth"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_16sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16sp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarWeek"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvLimWeekEnter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvLimWeekEnter"
        android:max="100"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarMonth"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvLimMonthEnter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvLimMonth"
        android:max="100"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I only want to show the progress bars, when there is a limit, otherwise I want to remove them. This is my adapter for the RecyclerView:

```
class CategoryAdapter(private val mCats: List<Category>, private val context: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryViewHolder>(){
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CategoryViewHolder {
    return CategoryViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.categories_view, parent, false))
}

override fun getItemCount() = mCats.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CategoryViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val cat: Category = mCats[position]
    holder.tvCat.text = cat.cat_name
    if(cat.limit_week != null)
        holder.tvLimitWeekEnter.text = cat.limit_week.toString()
    else {
        holder.tvLimitWeek.height = 0
        holder.tvLimitWeekEnter.height = 0
    }
    if(cat.limit_month != null)
        holder.tvLimitMonthEnter.text = cat.limit_month.toString()
    else {
        holder.tvLimitMonth.height = 0
        holder.tvLimitMonthEnter.height = 0
    }
}
```

}

I don't know if I can somehow remove the TextViews, soI just set the height to 0. But now I need to remove the progress bars, where I can't change the height. So is there a way to remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setVisibility(View.GONE)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) on your progress bars to make them invisible and not take any space for layout purposes.

Answer (score 0):

you can change visibility on your progress bar